# What is wrong with the string formatting in my line of code, and why does it say: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've just recently started coding and came across this problem which I can not seem to solve. This is my code:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
quest = input("What is your quest? ")
color =input("What is your favorite color? ")
print ("Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, ") \
("and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color))
```

and this is the problem:

```
line 6, in <module>
  ("and your favorite color is %s.") % (name, quest, color)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra paretheses and have something like

```
print ("Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, \

and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not using the line separation operator properly, so you are treating the result of print, which is `None`, as a callable.

Look at the following:

```
print ("Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, ")
```

That will print:

```
Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s,
```

and calling `print` will return `None`, so following your code you will have:

```
None("and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color))
```

which is generating this error.

You can solve this problem by:

```
print ("Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, "
    "and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color))
```

I strongly encourage you to use f-string if you are using Python 3.6+:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
quest = input("What is your quest? ")
color = input("What is your favorite color? ")

print(f"Ah, so your name is {name}, your quest is {quest}, and your favorite color is {color}")
```

Notice how using f-strings improves the readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.format()` or the even [formatted string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
quest = input("What is your quest? ")
color =input("What is your favorite color? ")
print ("Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is {}, and your favorite color is {}"
       .format(name, quest, color))
```

or

```
print (f"Ah, so your name is {name}, your quest is {quest}, "\
       "and your favorite color is {color}")
```

for:

```
What is your name? What is your quest? What is your favorite color? Ah, so your name is a, your quest is b, and your favorite color is c
```

Doku:

- [pep 498 string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: OMG! THX! That was really helpful!